# Receiving username password in asp.net webform sent from android app

Tags: android, asp.net

I have successfully sent (username/password) and received (true/false) values from my android app to .php page.
Now i am trying to replace php page with aspx page
I am having problem while receiving data at Asp.net page (android app to asp.net page), so pls help me in this regard with asp.net page.

My android code is as follows:

```
    public void postLoginData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xyz/Default.aspx"); 
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("formData1", x));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("formData2", y));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry about formatting, have posted question for first time.

Comment: And what is the result or exception?

Comment: Thank you Slukian for formatting..

Comment: I have added my android code too, here i m trying to send username and password using post method to default.aspx. I am not sure whether my default.aspx is able to receive/read the username/password or not.

Comment: Guys, got it right this time, made necessary changes...in the above code..above code is good to go with !!!

Comment: instead of post the answer in the question, you should create an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//   Successful asp.net code is as follows:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
 {
  string result,x,y;
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
             x = Page.Request.Form["formData1"];
             y = Page.Request.Form["formData2"];

        if (x == y)
        {
            result = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "false";
        }

        Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(result));
        Response.End();
    }
 }
```

Comment: i think aspx works different from php, in ASPX you have to set your request vars in code behind ON LOAD event.